# Reports neither getting displayed nor getting any error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, report

I am trying to display Report for my Windows application in VS 2015.
its on Button Click and have two DateTimePicker controls for selecting From and To dates.The Problem is that i don't encounter any error when running the application Although the selected from and to dates are getting displayed in the report but not the Data.

Below is the code

```
        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

        MyDataSetTableAdapters.GetDataReportTableAdapter ta = new MyDataSetTableAdapters.GetDataReportTableAdapter();
        MyDataSet.GetDataReportDataTable dt = new MyDataSet.GetDataReportDataTable();
        ta.Fill(dt);
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        rds.Name = "DataSet1";
        rds.Value = dt;

        ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("fromDate", dtFromDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
        ReportParameter rp2 = new ReportParameter("toDate", dtToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp1);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp2);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

         }
```

Please Help.

Comment: Add a break point on "ta.Fill(dt);" line and step through then see if dt object is populated from the data source. In addition you can use try..catch to see if any exception been rasied.

Comment: nope nothing did that already.when i go to my dataset and preview data its working properly

Comment: i cant see any dataset in your posted code. If you are not getting anything in the dt object then the issue may be in the ta object or in MyDataSetTableAdapters.GetDataReportTableAdapter(); method.

Comment: its throwing nonimplementedexception The method or operation is not implemented changed  ta.Fill(dt,dtFromDate,dtToDate);   i googled about it and some say to comment it out or restart will fix it but nothing has worked for me so far.

Comment: Okay - Appearently you code looks fine, there are however rooms for improvement but thats not relevent to your problem. I think the problem is within these two lines 
 MyDataSetTableAdapters.GetDataReportTableAdapter ta = new MyDataSetTableAdapters.GetDataReportTableAdapter();
        MyDataSet.GetDataReportDataTable dt = new MyDataSet.GetDataReportDataTable();

Comment: i have created Stored Procedure because data retrieval is from 2 tables.In those two lines i am retrieving data from stored procedure only. how else should i retrieve if not like this any idea?

Comment: Try to use DataReader and return your data set in a List of POCO object. Something like this public List<MyDataObject> GetDataFromStoredProc(); You can upload your solution on GitHub and send me the link, I can take a look later this evening.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved The Issue by Creating new Stored Procedure and accessing data from it.

```
     ta.Fill(dt,dtFromDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),dtToDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

this changes should be done while autobinding datasource to reportviewer.

Comment: So the problem was not in the posted code in your question then.